# SignalR client for Ruby

Tags: asp.net, ruby, websocket, signalr

I have a task for my project to connect to ASP.NET SignalR websocket to fetch some data in real-time from Ruby program. The problem is I couldn't find any single SignalR client for Ruby. As I understand, SignalR version of websockets is a bit different from e.g. socket.io, there are some instances called "Hubs", so I guess special client is needed.

Can I connect to SignalR websocket from Ruby using any existing solutions, or do I need to write client from scratch?

Comment: Websockets is part of the HTML5 specification and client support is built into modern browsers. So if you're talking about something other than server-to-browser communication, it is a bit non-standard. Regardless, this is not the proper forum for this type of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. Signalr server side is called Signalr hub and each client will be connected to this hub. Using socket.io client is not possible and you need a client supporting Signalr protocol.Unfortunately, there are no ruby projects or at least well-maintained ones right now.
You can implement a one which is sure not an overnight work or use a hack such as host an existing signalr client and talk to your ruby client from there.